# Some keys act as a arrows or type numbers

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I don't know what I did but now some keys from the keyboard are not typing the corresponding letter but move the cursor instead. The expected letter is typed if I press the <kbd>fn</kbd> key at the same time. With the <kbd>shift</kbd> key pressed the funny keys type numbers.

I've read about a similar issue where the <kbd>numlock</kbd> key was activated. There is no <kbd>numlock</kbd> on this keyboard. I've installed `numlockx` and `run 'numlockx off'` : no change! With `'numlockx on'` : the funny keys type numbers.

I've tried rebooting off course: nope...

Here an image of the keyboard : [image: keyboard]

Comment: It is not clear to me from your highlighting, what you have run in the terminal. You should not run `run 'numlockx off'`, instead run `numlockx off` - without the "run" and without the quotation marks. ...sorry if this sounds stupid, I just want to make sure that your mistake is not there

Comment: Is this in the upper right corner of your keyboard a "scroll lock" key? If so, it could also have to do with this behaviour.

Comment: It sounds like your laptop has a built-in way to use certain keys like a keypad, even though it's not marked on the keyboard. My best guess is that fn+scroll lock sets it, but you should get the manual for you model at Sony support.

Comment: The numlock can often also be set to default on or off in the bios.

Comment: This is not a Sony's issue. It is not happens with Windows. Only in linux. In my case it is Mint Rebecca.

Comment: I'm original poster: problem appears each time my battery dries out. After every subsequent reboots, the keys are acting weird (as described). The way I solve the problem when it happens: go to BIOS; don't do any change; Save and Exit; et voilà!